# How do I write my first LINQ query using c# from scratch?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I checked many tutorials but none is helping me.
I use EF 6 and .Net 4.5
Well I have class AccountsContext which has the following

```
public class AccountingContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TransactionType> TransactionTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    }
}
```

and I am trying to call it from another class in the same namespace where i included

```
using Entity.Data;


List<Account> AccountsEntity = (from x in Accounts select x).ToList();
           account = (from acc in AccountsEntity
            where acc.AccountName == name 
            select acc).FirstOrDefault();
```

I keep getting that Accounts does not exist in the current context and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need a DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738447(v=vs.100).aspx) for your query, e.g.

```
using (AccountingContext ctx = new AccountingContext())
{
    List<Account> AccountsEntity = (from x in ctx.Accounts select x).ToList();
}
```

Note that `List<Account> AccountsEntity` should be `List<Account> accountsEntity` according to Microsoft's naming and casing conventions.